# How do I modify the structure of a live Firebase DB?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase realtime database that was architected very poorly by the original developer, and I need to drastically change its structure and move the existing data around. Is it possible to migrate the existing data without literally copy and pasting items? You know, the sort of thing that's trivially easy with an ordinary database....

Comment: I think the best way to do it is by exporting the data using Firebase Console, modify the data locally (using any programing language you'd like to automate the modification), then import the data back into Console.

Comment: Sorry, but with the information you've provided there is no way for us to answer. Focus on a specific case where you think the data is wrong, think of how you'd prefer the data to be for that case, check the code that currently produces and that consumes that data. Within such a specific context, we *might* be able to help.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid exporting the JSON, but I guess that's the only way to do it. Firebase is clearly not built for heavy-duty long term use